# Access to listview not available

Tags: android, listview, service, methods

Ok I have a big problem here.

I have a service that must accest a listview(in a xml file ofcourse). I tried with findviewbyid,ofcourse it did not work,cause it's not an activity.

Then I tried to make a static var with that listview in the main activity.Surprise! You can't make it static cause it uses findviewbyid.

I also tried to make a function in the main activity that returns a listview. The code looks ok,however when the app gets to that function crashes. In the log it apears because of a nullpointer...

Can someone tell me how to acces that listview if I'm in a service? It's annoying!

In the main activity,at onCreate the code is:

```
    UpdateDisplay();

    countdown();
    startService(new Intent(this, ss.class));
```

The source for the listview:

```
private void UpdateDisplay() //was private and void
    {
        TextView feedtitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.feedtitle);
        TextView feedpubdate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.feedpubdate);
        ListView itemlist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.itemlist);


        if (feed == null)
        {
            feedtitle.setText("No RSS Feed Available");
            return;
        }

        feedtitle.setText(feed.getTitle());
        feedpubdate.setText(feed.getPubDate());

        ArrayAdapter<RSSItem> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<RSSItem>(this ,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,feed.getAllItems());

        itemlist.setAdapter(adapter);

        itemlist.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        itemlist.setSelection(0);

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can someone tell me how to acces that listview if I'm in a service?

This is impossible. Services are not expected to deal with UI elements directly.

You can update your question with WHY do you need a `ListView` in a `Service`. So others could point you in a right direction.

Comment: Because I need to check if that listview contains String "Home" every 30 minutes. Actually I'll have many listviews to check,that's why I need to use that in a service.

Comment: Does the underlaying collection for the list view changes in time? If not then you don't need to access the list view directly, you can access it via `getResources().getStringArray(R.array.itemlist)`.

Comment: It doesn't change in time...I used that code but the app still crashes.Is that even correct with R.array? I mean it's a listview! In the log it shows that it crashes because it can't find the resource! BTW i checked and the service starts after the loading functions are called for the feed!

Comment: Look, please edit your question and post your code of (1) how you defined array resource and (2) how you check it in the service. Otherwise I feel like we're not on the same page.

Comment: edited. And on the service,I have nothing atm,it's empty. I'll have all the code at onHandleIntent

Comment: OMG. So you don't have the array resource. You probably get items from the network. Ok, I'd suggest to go with this plan: (1) get the items, (2) write it to the file, (3) start service, (4) service will be able to read the file and process.

Comment: yep. Or I'll put a function to check what I want in the local activity after the list is populated,and service will just restart the activity every 30 minutes. Thanks man!

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html

Comment: Guys, when downvoting please also state a reason, otherwise this just smells like a bad game.

Comment: I actually suck at using adapters. I tried to use:  String[] thelist = getResources().getStringArray(R.id.itemlist); but I get crash (log shows because of resources) and the adapter doesn't work,cause of setAdapter.

Comment: I believe `getStringArray(R.id.itemlist);` should be `getStringArray(R.array.itemlist);`.